# get Array as Output from stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAttritionData`(IN `supid` BIGINT, IN `from_date` DATE, IN `to_date` DATE, OUT `attr_rate` FLOAT, OUT `TERM_EMP_CNT` INT) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE CNT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE TOT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE AVG_HCOUNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT count(employee_id) INTO TERM_EMP_CNT FROM employee WHERE term_date between from_date and to_date AND app_role=1; 
WHILE from_date<=to_date DO 
SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) INTO CNT_EMP FROM employee WHERE sup_id=supid AND doj<from_date AND (term_date>from_date OR term_date='0000-00-00') AND app_role=1; 
SET from_date=date_add(from_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
SET i=i+1; 
SET TOT_EMP = TOT_EMP + CNT_EMP; 
END WHILE; 
SET AVG_HCOUNT=(TOT_EMP/i)*365/12; 
SET attr_rate = TERM_EMP_CNT/AVG_HCOUNT; 
END
```

I want attr_rate as an array, where it have 1 key and another is value such as

```
attr_rate[6-2015]=3.5
attr_rate[7-2015]=6.2
attr_rate[8-2015]=3.3
```

how to declare an array in MySQL Stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: `'array'` is not supported. Instead *prepare* and execute an sql statement that generates the result set with your desired `'array_index'` and `'value'`